# Automatically detect new versions of Ionic 3 app in PlayStore

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, version

I’m trying to release my first `ionic app`. I want to know how users get to know that there is a new update in `PlayStore` and how do they download it ?

What is the `Ionic Native App Update` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update/ 2) ?

And is it enough to increase the `version no` in `config.xml` when app build for a new updated release?

**widget id="io.ionic.888" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"**

Comment: If you want to update your existing app on playstore then just upload with different version i.e. if you have `0.0.1` on playstore upload with `0.0.2` so you will update.

Comment: You mean that I don't want to install any library to my app. Only thing I have to do is increase the app version no ?

Comment: helpful question @GunarathneMDD

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `App Update plugins` to verify that updates is available at playstore.

```
Repo: https://github.com/vaenow/cordova-plugin-app-update

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-update
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/app-update
```

You should first host an XML file on your server with the following data in it:

```
<update>
    <version>302048</version>
    <name>APK Name</name>
    <url>https://your-remote-api.com/YourApp.apk</url>
</update>
```

Then use the following code app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppUpdate } from '@ionic-native/app-update';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    constructor(private appUpdate: AppUpdate) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            const updateUrl = 'https://your-remote-api.com/update.xml';
            this.appUpdate.checkAppUpdate(updateUrl).then(() => { console.log('Update available') });
        });
    }
}
```

The plugin will compare the app version and prompt update if the API has a newer version to install.

Comment: OK, then to what url, I must put my playstore apk url

Comment: your remote web server APK URL: https://your-remote-api.com/YourApp.apk in update.xml file.

Comment: Sorry, I only put my apk in PlayStore, not in remote web server.

Comment: I'm confused with the XML `<version>302048</version>`.
How do I define the version? Is it the one I used with `<widget version="1.0.0" ...>`? If so, if I define a new update, this goes as `<version>1.0.1</version>`?

Comment: Don't use this plugin! Google play suspending apps that are using this plugin github issue: https://github.com/vaenow/cordova-plugin-app-update/issues/146